# How can I format this mongoose updateone query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

UPDATE: I adjusted the query using arrayFilters that someone here recommened, the query comes back as success, however values are never changed in the db.

I am trying to update certain fields within a mongodb collection according the the values passed to the database function.

```
module.exports.update_sprint = async function 
       update_sprint(teamname, update_data, sprint, sprintStar) {

    for(var i in update_data) {
      console.log(update_data[i].stars)
      console.log(update_data[i].name)
      TeamM.findOneAndUpdate({teamName: teamname}, {
        $set: {
          'sprints.$[a].stars.$[b].stars': update_data[i].stars,
          'sprints.$[a].stars.$[b].points': update_data[i].points,
          'sprints.$[a].sprintstars': sprintStar
        }
      }, {arrayFilters: [{"a.sprintnum": sprint}, {"b.name": 
update_data[i].name}]}
      ,
      function(error, success) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        } else {
          console.log(success)
        }}
      )

}
```

}

Database format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwmA8.png)

I am getting:

```
1
member1@lewisu.edu
0
member2@lewisu.edu
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61b90840654b60a745e7e102"),
  teamName: 'testing',
  members: [ 'member1@lewisu.edu', 'member2@lewisu.edu' ],
  scrumMaster: 'member1@lewisu.edu',
  totalMembers: 2,
  sprints: [ { sprintnum: 1, stars: [Array], sprintstar: 'None' } ],
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61b90840654b60a745e7e102"),
  teamName: 'testing',
  members: [ 'member1@lewisu.edu', 'member2@lewisu.edu' ],
  scrumMaster: 'member1@lewisu.edu',
  totalMembers: 2,
  sprints: [ { sprintnum: 1, stars: [Array], sprintstar: 'None' } ],
  __v: 0
}
```

The query is coming back as success, however values are not updated in the database

Comment: the result tells you that `modifiedCount` = 0, meaning that there were no matching entries to be modified

Comment: I see that, but the the entry is there, I just do not think I am setting the search parameters correctly.

Comment: can you provide the logging of your teamname and sprintum from the request?

Comment: updated the output

Answer (score 0):

In your request u want to match sprints = sprintum, you just have to change it to this:

```js
Test.updateOne({ teamName: "test123", "sprints.sprintnum": 1 }, { // Mistake was  in this line
            $set: {
                'sprints.$.stars': update_data,
                'sprints.$.sprintstar': sprintStar
            }
        })
```

Before:

```js
{
  "teamName": "test123",
  "members": [
    "test@lewisu.edu",
    "test@lewisu.edu"
  ],
  "scrumMaster": "test@lewisu.edu",
  "totalMembers": 2,
  "sprints": [
    {
      "sprintum": 1,
      "stars": [
        {
          "name": "test@lewisu.edu",
          "stars": 0,
          "points": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "test2@lewisu.edu",
          "stars": 0,
          "points": 0
        }
      ],
      "sprintstar": "None"
    }
  ]
}
```

After:

[image]

As of your comment I added an example for multiple identifiers:

```js
Test.updateOne({ teamName: "test123" }, {
            $set: {
                'sprints.$[i].stars.$[j].stars': 5,
                'sprints.$[i].sprintstar': "test@lewisu.edu"
            }
        }, { arrayFilters: [{ "i.sprintum": 1 }, { "j.name": "test@lewisu.edu" }] })
```

This will update in the array with sprintum one the stars of the person in the stars array with the name "test@lewisu.edu"

With this you can basically do everything you want in all the arrays in your document

Comment: Im not sure how sprintnum, ended up being misspelled, after fixing, however, I am still not updating values. It is still finding the entry, however what I think is throwing it off is the numeric ordering of subentries and not being able to reference it, for instance, the stars: array has entries listing in numeric order 0, 1. The more this application would be used, the more entries under stars there would be. But then again, I am very new to mongoose.

Comment: If you want to controle multiple nested arrays you can use arrayFilters, they are the 3rd parameter in the updateOne() function.
Here a link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/
You could access the objects you want by first identifying the object with sprintum = 1 and then the one with name  = test@lewisu.edu and adjust the points there

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example for arrayFilters at the bottom for you

Comment: The query is now working annd coming back as success, however for some reason the values are not changing in the db. I updated the code, the db schema due to spelling errors, and provided new output. Thank you for the help

Comment: So the request returns a properly updated document but the database does not save the changes?

Comment: In your 3rd $set line you set sprintstars<--- with an s, in your provided database format the field does NOT have the s.
Also you have it named sprint(n)um while the database format does not have the n

Comment: I fixed sprintstar, and sprintnum was how it was always suppose to be. I fixed the mongodb image to reflect that as well. Yes, the request returns a updated document, but where the changes occured happen inside the [Array] part of the output and cannot tell what the changes it tried to make.

Comment: you can use JSON.stringify(success, null, " ") in the log or use console.info(success) to display the result with arrays written out , if the result actually is NOT updated, then you still have spelling mistakes, because the code I sent works fine for me and only differs in spelling, not logic